# React + Redux state with multiple uses

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't have a code to share. I am using a template that's built using react + Redux.

The issue I ran into is that if I want multiple users to use the app, the state gets shared with everyone. It makes no difference between users. So the problem I have is one use will see the state of another user who just logged in before. Another one is I am fetching data to display in a chart and somehow the numbers are incrementing everytime it fetches and gets worse if multiple users are logged in.

My question is... How do you manage a react app with multiple users along with Redux? It seems most tutorial I found somehow assume there is only one user.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with React or Redux. If multiple logged in users share the same state, in means there's a server involved that doesn't store data based on user id's or sessions. You need to show relevant backend (node) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easiest solution is, if your APP is using database that fetched from an API, everytime you start your request, you should clear the data first

here's my reducer example (I'm using redux-tools)

```
 reducers: {
    getRoleDetailStart(state) {
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].data = {};
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].isLoading = true;
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].error = null;
    },
    getRoleDetailSuccess(state, action) {
      const { data } = action.payload;
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].data = data;
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].isLoading = false;
      state[CURRENT_NAMESPACE].error = null;
    },
    getRoleDetailError(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
```

actions

```
export const fetchRootGetRoleDetail = ({ roleId }) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  const state = getState();
  const selectedState = state[PARENT_NAMESPACE][CURRENT_NAMESPACE];
  const { isLoading } = selectedState;
  if (isLoading) return;
  try {
    dispatch(getRoleDetailStart());
    const data = await restRootGetRoleDetail({
      roleId,
    });
    dispatch(
      getRoleDetailSuccess({
        data,
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    if (isValidJSON(err)) {
      return dispatch(getRoleDetailError(JSON.parse(err).message));
    }
    dispatch(getRoleDetailError(err));
  }
};
```